# Searching data in react-data-table-component from search button?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint

I want to create a search button to search data in react-data-table-component using get rest api. So far what I have done when user clicks on user_tab on a page it searches and fetched all data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For search, you need to pass an array object to the table which filtered on conditions.
There are two ways:

- One is you fectch all the records, and in your local state you apply condition and filter according to searches. You will pass a filtered array to your table means a newArray or newObject.
- Second and recumended way for search is, you create an end point in your server side and send a request for a specific data.

Answer (score 3):

I know this was posted a while ago, but you can use the React Data Table Component extension, wich will filter all the data of your entire table, wether if you're using data from an API or mocked data.
You can read about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component-extensions)
Basically, after you install the library you're gonna run

```js
$ npm install react-data-table-component-extensions
```

The syntax is pretty much this: [Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/3dy9p?file=/src/index.js:650-655)

```js
import React from "react";
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";
import DataTableExtensions from "react-data-table-component-extensions";

import { columns, data } from "./data";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <DataTableExtensions
          columns={columns}
          data={data}
          print={false}
          export={false}
        >
          <DataTable
            // columns={columns}
            // data={data}
            noHeader
            // defaultSortField="id"
            // defaultSortAsc={false}
            pagination
            highlightOnHover
          />
        </DataTableExtensions>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And BOOM, you have a filter thar works perfectly nice with your DataTable

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30049887)

Comment: Thank you for the advide, I've updated my answer

Comment: This plugin is having a document error with new versions, as after uploading code to VERCEL the vercel compiler is throwing this error in PLUGIN file where you have no control.